# Iterate image size without using loop?

Tags: python, image, numpy, loops, image-processing

```
row,col = 4000, 4000  
a =np.zeros((row*col,6))
k=0
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        if k<len(a):
           a[k, 1:3]= [i,j] #Put pixsel coordinates in even rows -- 1. and 2. columns.
           k = k + 2
```

There is an image with size 4000,4000 and I want to iterate pixel coordinate each point(iterate size).I did this just like above.But image size is big and this process takes a lot of time.Is there a more efficient way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without looping, however I was some what unclear on why you were only returning coordinates up half of the row, ie in my example the last non zero row is coordinates (4,9) hence in pix() rows is set to 5 instead of 10.

Original function:

```
def pixels():
    row,col = 10, 10 
    a =np.zeros((row*col,6))
    k=0
    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
            if k<len(a):
                a[k, 1:3]= [i,j] #Put pixsel coordinates in even rows -- 1. and 2. columns.
                k = k + 2
    return a
```

New function with looping:

```
def pix():
    row,col = 5, 10
    N = 2
    a = np.meshgrid(np.arange(row), np.arange(col), indexing='ij')
    b = np.transpose(a,np.roll(np.arange(N + 1), -1)).reshape(-1, N)
    z=np.zeros_like(b)
    s=np.hstack([b,z]).reshape(-1,2)
    l = np.zeros((s.shape[0],1), dtype=np.int)
    r = np.zeros((s.shape[0],3), dtype=np.int)

    return np.hstack([l, s, r])
```

Comparison:

```
>>> a=pix()
>>> b=pixels()
>>> np.all(b==a)
True
```

Performance:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(pix, number=1000)
0.08045329099695664
>>> timeit.timeit(pixels, number=1000)
0.1498899580037687
```

Output of pix():

```
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 4, 9, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: You’re welcome. An up arrow and accepted answer would be appreciated! ;)